# Obtaining smooth Hough lines from image with rough edges in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, hough-transform

I have images in this link: https://imgur.com/a/TZPuz?&nc&nc

The 1st image is my original image, the 2nd one compares the original image with the image after applying the code below:

```
I=imread('sample.png');
I = rgb2gray(I);
E = edge(I, 'canny');
Edil = imdilate(E, strel('disk', 2));
Idil = imgaussfilt(double(Edil), 2); %2nd image in link, left one
Idil = imgaussfilt(double(Edil), 8); %2nd image in link, right one
```

The 3rd image is the result of using `Hough`:

```
BW=Idil;
[H,T,R] = hough(BW,'Theta',89:0.3:89.9);
P  = houghpeaks(H,5,'threshold',ceil(0.3*max(H(:))));
x = T(P(:,2)); y = R(P(:,1));
% Find lines and plot them
lines = houghlines(BW,T,R,P,'FillGap',5,'MinLength',7);
figure, imshow(Ib), hold on
max_len = 0;
for k = 1:length(lines)
  xy = [lines(k).point1; lines(k).point2];
  plot(xy(:,1),xy(:,2),'LineWidth',2,'Color','green');
  % Plot beginnings and ends of lines
  plot(xy(1,1),xy(1,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','yellow');
  plot(xy(2,1),xy(2,2),'x','LineWidth',2,'Color','red');
end
```

However, this image isn't what I expected. I was hoping it would produce lines similar to the 4th or 5th images in the link

How can I improve this so I get the Hough lines I prefer?

EDIT: When I modified `numpeaks` parameter for `houghpeaks`, I got the lines I expected

However, isn't there a way Matlab can automatically detect the number of edges? Because I have a bunch of images that are a little different from the sample image I provided, and most of them will not have the same number of edges with each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't apply the Canny edge detector to your image. You are detecting lines in the edge image, which will give you a line for each edge in your input image. Your input image contains lines that you want to detect, apply Hough directly to it.

Optionally, you can filter your input image to make the lines thinner, yielding a nicer Hough transform. Look for `bwmorph` and the `'thin'` option.

Comment: This is what I got after your suggestions: https://imgur.com/a/p3wqv - the first image without Canny Edge, the 2nd one using `bwmorph` and `thin`. These results are still not desirable

Comment: Next you need to improve how you detect the local maxima (didn't look into how `houghpeaks` works, sorry), and stop expecting that a system designed to detect straight lines will detect a wriggly line.

Comment: I mean, if you cut off your line every time it exits the wriggly line in the input, you'll never be able to fit it throughout the whole line. There is no straight line that extends across the image and sits inside your wriggly line.

Comment: The straight lines I want don't need to fit exactly within the wriggly line. I just want straight line approximations. It is also ok if there was a way to fit a thin rectangular (or some other polygonal object) box that contains each edge, instead of having a straight line that fits the edges. Is this possible to do in Matlab?

Comment: There are many methods to detect lines. It very much depends on your application what the most suitable one is. Are the images linked representative, or are those a simplification? Because binary or nearly binary images like those would be pretty trivial to process. How to do this is more than fits in a comment box, and giving you a good solution would require more time from me as well. Look for connected component analysis to get started.